# Capture contents of div into an image

Tags: php, html

Does anybody know if it is possible to grab a capture of a particular div using php? What I would like to do is have a drag and drop container where users could potentially position a number of images using javascript and then I would like them to be able to save a copy of the result as a single image.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, work out the coordinates of the images placed with javascript and assign them to a hidden form field. Then save it using PHP and store the coordinates in the database...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canvas.toDataURL()` from the html 5 canvas element to save it into a image file. You can get more info [Here](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/save-html5-canvas-data-as-image.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can load the images into a canvas field (`drawImage()`) and implement drag and drop functions. If the user presses the send button, the canvas will be converted to a data URL with  `canvas.toDataURL()`.

But I think it's simplier when you only save the coordinates and let PHP merge the images.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done only with javascript. And if you need the image on server, you can sent it by ajax.

Take a look at [this jQuery tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/22/interactive-image-vamp-up-with-jquery-css3-and-php/) which does something close that you want. ([demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ImageVampUp/))